# Electromagnetic radiations

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

I am trying to understand the phenomenon why electric and magnetic  field is represented in the form of waves in the propagation of electromagnetic radiations.  [image: Electric and magnetic fields are in the form of waves as is shown in picture]

Comment: Have you looked in any textbooks on E&M? There should be a whole chapter on the subject....

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking why E and B fields satisfy the wave equation? I'm curious: According to your understanding, how should em radiation be represented?

Comment: Maybe it would helpful for you first to read [What are photons, EM radiation an EM waves]](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90646/what-is-the-relation-between-electromagnetic-wave-and-photon/253957#253957).